# How to properly use i2c.writeto_then_readfrom() method

Tags: i2c, python, adafruit

*See also follow-up question about [i2c addresses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/638252/173919)*

I have this [mikroe](https://www.mikroe.com/rs232-to-i2c-click) board wired up to an [S2 Feather](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4769?gclid=Cj0KCQjwy5maBhDdARIsAMxrkw0HE8TVy7uXMbaFZx5ISJmWvXYYELbvFJlHUGSPgfoQNW-pigGif8MaAmJBEALw_wcB) via the `SDA` and `SCL` pins. The Mikroe board is powered by the Feather via `3v3` and `GND`. I have 2k pullup resistors to `3v3` on the `SDA` and `SCL` pins.

Having run and I2C scan, I returned the following two addresses: `0x53` and `0x5b` on the Mikroe board. At this point, feel free to have a look at the [datasheet](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/ZDU0110RFX_datasheet.pdf).

I want to read the EEPROM, so I have tried:

```
result = bytearray(8)
i2c.writeto_then_readfrom(0x5b, result, result)
print(result)
```

this returns:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00)
```

So then I think I need to send the address of the EEPROM read command to the mikroe board, which is listed as `0x01` in the datasheet. I try to load various commands from the datasheet into my `writeto_then_readfrom_function` such as `0x01` and `0xe5` (simple system status) in various ways.

I have tried to append the address to the buffer using:

```
result = bytearray.append(0x01)
```

But that returns

```
TypeError: argument has wrong type
```

So I tried to load it in as a byte, thinking that surely a bytearray can contain bytes:

```
test = bytes(0xe5)
result = bytearray.append(test)
```

But, sure enough, I have the same error. So how to I actually send the appropriate command to the Mikroe board so it transmits the data back to the buffer? Perhaps this isn't even the appropriate method? As an aside I have tried all of the examples above using the other address, `0x53` as well.

Comment: You have three different problems. First basic usage of Python variables. Next is how to use the I2C module your MCU provides in Python. The last is how to access the memory data using the I2C module. Solve them one by one, there must be manuals and tutorials available - if not then how can anyone use that MCU board for any purpose. For example, I have no clue what exactly the writeto-readfrom method does even if I can guess, but you need to link to the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Great point. I will mark this as solved because @jonathanjo worked out the basic usage in python. I will dig around in the I2c module and ask a more intelligent question next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending to the wrong thing.  `append` is a *method* on bytearrays, and so is invoked on the object you want to append to, in order to pass that object in to the function as its first argument<sup>Note</sup>.

I believe you meant this:

```
>>> result = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> result.append(0x01)
>>> result
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')
```

<sup><sup>Tested on Python 3.6.9</sup></sup>

**That's your Python problem** solved: I see your follow-up [question about i2c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/638252/173919)

---

Note: this is a common stumbling block in Python, and is either very opaque or completely obvious depending on your Python knowledge.

We think of a class function as being "the same as" the instance method, and they both look like attributes.

> when `C` is a class which contains a definition for a function `f()`, and `x` is an instance of `C`, calling `x.f(1)` is equivalent to calling `C.f(x, 1)`. -- [Python Reference: Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

This is most visible by looking at the signatures:

```
import inspect # standard library for inspecting functions

>>> C = bytearray
>>> x = C()

>>> C.append
<method 'append' of 'bytearray' objects>
>>> inspect.signature(C.append)
<Signature (self, item, /)>

>>> x.append
<built-in method append of bytearray object at 0x7f840aeba998>
>>> inspect.signature(x.append)
<Signature (item, /)>
```

Comment: Wow! What a simple mistake and great job catching it. That being said, when I fix it as you suggest the buffer actually returns "none" and as a result the i2c.writeto... method gets a type error that object with bufffer protocol is required. I don't know why appending to result changes the type. I tried "loading" into test as well but that returns error of can't convert bytes to int